# Apache Wicket - Adding HTML to feedback panel

Tags: java, html, apache, custom-controls, wicket

Is there a way to add custom HTML to the FeedbackPanel?

As in, instead of only adding the `<span>` element to the `<li>` the FeedbackPanel creates for each added message, I'd like to add a `<div>` with a `<button>` and the `<span>`.

So I'm looking for something like `validationErrorFeedback.error(message);` where message would be my HTML. Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can subclass `FeedbackPanel` and hence provide your own markup. Just copy `FeedbackPanel.html` and edit the markup as you wish (the component hierarchy must still be the same though).

Answer (score 3):

The easiest looking way is to call

```
feedbackPanel#setEscapeModelStrings(false)
```

But if you do this, your application is vulnerable to a cross-site scripting attack if you have any validators which display the input back. For example, if you have a text field using EmailAddressValidator and a user inputs 'Joe', the validator's error message will show is:

```
'${input}' is not a valid email address.
```

Which will return 'Joe' is not a valid email address. However - an attacker can inject an XSS payload pretty easily by passing `<script>alert('xss')</script>` for example, which is no longer escaped.

If you can guarantee that none of your validators will echo this input back - go ahead and use it. Otherwise you'll need to do as Mr. Leiter suggests and subclass FeedbackPanel with your own markup. In wicket 1.5.x this looks like:

```
<html xmlns:wicket="http://wicket.apache.org">
<body>
<wicket:panel>
  <ul wicket:id="feedbackul" class="feedbackPanel">
    <li wicket:id="messages" class="errorlevel">
      <span wicket:id="message" class="errorlevel">A message</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</wicket:panel>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the XSS insight. I will take the safe path and do it as Leiter said. Thanks for the markup too.